# Exception has occurred. RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..4: 5)

Tags: flutter, dart

My app randomizes a list and pushes items in order and shows in the screen, but when the list is over, the app crashes and shows this exception.

[image]

```
    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
    
      var pergunta = "randomquest";

      int _posicao1 = -1;
    
      var lista1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']..shuffle();
    
    void Teste1 (){
      _posicao1++;
      setState(() {
      pergunta = lista1.elementAt(_posicao1);
    });
    }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white, 
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[ 
                      IconButton(   
                        icon: Image.asset('images/eye.png'),
                        iconSize: 150,
                        onPressed: () {Teste1();
                        },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_posicao1 is reaching '5' in Teste1() and asking for elementAt(5), which doesn't exist. Lists in Dart are zero-based, which means they start at 0. Your list has 5 elements: 0,1,2,3,4.  You could do a bounds check in Teste1():

Start the loop over

```
void Teste1 (){
  _posicao1++;
  if(_posicao1 == lista1.length) _posicao1 = 0; //start the loop over
  setState(() {
      pergunta = lista1.elementAt(_posicao1);
  });
}
```

Stay on the last element

```
void Teste1 (){
  _posicao1++;
  if(_posicao1 == lista1.length) _posicao1 = lista1.length-1; //last index of lista1      
  setState(() {
      pergunta = lista1.elementAt(_posicao1);
  });
}
```